# Сохранить действие на стороне клиента

Tags: javascript

Есть кнопки:

```
<button onclick="ID('28229')">
<button onclick="ID('849494')">
<button onclick="ID('4040490')">
```

Есть объекты, которые содержат ид кнопки:

```
<div id="id28229" style="color:green"></div>
<div id="id849494" style="color:green"></div>
<div id="id4040490" style="color:green"></div>
```

Есть функция

```
<script>
#При нажатии на функцию
function ID(id) {
#Мы меняем цвет у элемента на красный
$("#id"+id).css("color","red");
}
</script>
```

Вопрос: при нажатии на новую кнопку, как вернуть прежнему элементу зеленый цвет текста, ведь в функцию приходит id нового элемента, а значение старого элемента я запомнить не могу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function ID(id) {
  $(".active").removeClass("active");
  $("#id" + id).addClass("active");
}
```

```css
.green {
  color: green;
}

.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="ID('28229')">A</button>
<button onclick="ID('849494')">B</button>
<button onclick="ID('4040490')">C</button>

<div id="id28229" class="green">AAA</div>
<div id="id849494" class="green">BBB</div>
<div id="id4040490" class="green">CCC</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот так мы можем запомнить!

```js
var color;
var id='28229'; //любой существующий id
function ID(id) {
color = $("#id"+id).css("color");
if (this.id!=id) {
  $("#id"+this.id).css("color",color);
  this.id=id;
  }
$("#id"+id).css("color","red");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="ID('28229')">Кнопка1</button>
<button onclick="ID('849494')">Кнопка2</button>
<button onclick="ID('4040490')">Кнопка3</button>
  
<div id="id28229" style="color:green">Текст</div>
<div id="id849494" style="color:green">Ещё</div>
<div id="id4040490" style="color:green">Текст</div>
```